# Blazor client app downloads data via the Blazor router when it should come from the server

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm writing a C# Server, Backend For Frontend (BFF) to work with a Blazor client. Intermittently I have noticed that a request for data from the BFF actually loads the index.html file from the Blazor fallback. The call is made using httpClient.

I have now observed that this occurs when my Server application is slow to start - it seems as though the browser loads the initial HTML page from cache because the server is not available, and then the entire client stack fetches data from the Blazor fallback. I guess this is designed to allow offline behaviour, but I'm not sure how to handle the situation.

Firstly I'm wondering, should I be implementing a more intelligent fallback routine that can serve cached data?

Then I'm wondering how you get the application back out of this situation - i.e. when the Server is available again, how do I get httpClient requests to go out onto the Internet again?

I'm finding it very odd - does anybody have experience/advice about this?

Thanks

Update:
I should've known I wouldn't get anywhere without posting code - I'll try and post what I think is relevant. It's a little bit complicated.

Authentication in my system is processed via an external instance of IdentityServer4, the login form is in the BFF, so if I want to authenticate the Blazor Client, it navigates the browser to a secure page in the BFF's MVC pages, this all works fine, the token is stored in an application cookie.

Once authenticated the Blazor client then calls a handler in the BFF to return a serialized view of the claims - Blazor will then act as if the user has the claims in the token.

Server Handler looks as follows:

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) => {
                //middleware to indicate to Blazor client what it's ClaimsIdentity should be
                if (context.Request.Path.Value?.ToLowerInvariant() == "/userinfo")
                {
                    var user = context.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
                    if (!(user?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false))
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("null");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var ident = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                        var userinfo = new
                        {
                            Claims = user.Claims.Select(c => new
                            {
                                c.Type,
                                c.Value,
                                c.Issuer,
                                c.OriginalIssuer,
                                c.Properties,
                                c.ValueType
                                //c.Subject - This is left out since it is circular on Identity
                            }),
                            Identity = new
                            {
                                //ident.Actor - This is left out since it is circular on Identity
                                //              in addition this should not be a delegated token
                                ident.AuthenticationType,

                                //ident.BootstrapContext, - Looks like this is always null, but if it were
                                //                          a token, sending it could leak it

                                //ident.Claims - This is left out since it is circular on claims
                                ident.IsAuthenticated,
                                ident.Label,
                                ident.Name,
                                ident.NameClaimType,
                                ident.RoleClaimType
                            }
                        };

                        var jici = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(userinfo);

                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(jici.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                }
            });
```

Blazor Client Call looks as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("Downloading /userinfo");
var wclient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("ProofOfDelivery.ServerAPI");
var claimsAndIdentity = await wclient.GetFromJsonAsync<DownloadClaimsAndIdentity>("/userinfo");
Console.WriteLine("#claims = " + (claimsAndIdentity?.Claims?.Count() ?? 0));
Console.WriteLine("Identity.Name = " + (claimsAndIdentity?.Identity?.Name ?? ""));
Console.WriteLine("Identity.AuthenticationType = " + (claimsAndIdentity?.Identity?.AuthenticationType ?? ""));
Console.WriteLine("Identity.IsAuthenticated = " + (claimsAndIdentity?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false));
```

The HttpClient was added to the DI container thus:

```
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ProofOfDelivery.ServerAPI",
                client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
```

The call in the client is wrapped in a general try .. catch so that anything wrong, 404, 500, Timeout etc. Loads a saved token from an IDBStore, 403/401 clears that token and the internal state is not authed.

Generally I need the GetFromJsonAsync to fail in some way if the server is unavailable, but I can see on Chromes network tag that the url /userinfo was downloaded, and it contains the fallback index.html file. If this were the cached/previous token download, then I'd be happy, indeed I'd need less code to do the offline stuff, but it's plain wrong. I can't work out how it got the content of index.html and I think that the Blazor Client caught the request and decided what to return from the cache.

So again - it works when the sever can serve /userinfo, but not when it can't.

Thanks

Comment: I apologise - the fallback path appears only in the Server BFF component, not the client, so I have no idea why a call to a url such as /api/delivernotes/list results in fetching the contents of index.html. It's all a mystery!

Comment: Can you share your controller code, please? I have encountered the same problem myself and it was either because my controller was not called properly or I did not use the correct port.